# Find same value and show data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

How can I assign values from the Germany tab and column B to the World tab. If, of course, the value in cell A matches the cell A in the germany tab. (I already see the match in red. I still need the numbers to transfer.)

Example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJZqpsWxy5CPvVmNHRZ29ZSTbUhfUiXvtABf1cwkmdY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;Germany!A1:B;2;FALSE);0)
```

If you paste this formula along every cell in B in World, you will get your result. If it doesn't find the value in Germany it will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A; Germany!A:B; 2; 0)))
```

[image]